# Set Docker resource limits via gitlab CICD as variables

Tags: docker, variables, gitlab, cicd

I'm trying to set some resource limits into a docker container. I'm able to add the below values to a docker-compose.yml file for docker resource limits;

```
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 4GB
        reservations:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4GB
```

How would I pass them in via gitlab pipeline for the container being built but set them as variables?

I was able to override the java heap size by adding;

`java_xmx=${JAVA_XMX_OVERRIDE}`

and the value

`JAVA_XMX_OVERRIDE: "-Xmx2048m"`

How would I do the same with resource limits?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use variables in docker compose which you can propagate with the starting command.

compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  httpd:
    container_name: httpd-test
    image: httpd
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: ${MEMORY}
```

Start container:

```
$ MEMORY=60M docker-compose up -d
$ docker stats
CONTAINER ID   NAME              CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O     PIDS
ace0d6d638e1   httpd-test        0.00%     26.86MiB / 60MiB      44.77%    4.3kB / 0B        0B / 0B       82
```

You should be able to define an environment variable in your gitlab pipeline:

```
variables:
  MEMORY: 60M
```

Comment: Can you pass them in without modifying the docker-compose file? I.e set them as extra vars when the container is being deployed?

Comment: You can change limitations of a running container via `docker update -m 50M container_name`

Comment: But then when the container is deployed via the pipeline in the future, those changes will be over-written?

Comment: If you can't modify your docker compose file, then the only way I see is to use `docker update` command in the pipeline after `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up adding a docker-compose file template in the pipeline, in the template I modified the resource limits with ansible

```
- name: Compose Docker | Get text block for service   set_fact:
      service_content: "{{ lookup('template', 'templates/docker-compose-service.yml.j2') }}"   tags:
    - compose_docker
```